# is there anyway to navigate in a React-Router V4 app from outside a react environment?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

i am making a app with 2 libraries along with `react`. i am using `leaflet` and `marzipano`.

i am using `Redux` as a dataSync.

now, i want to change the route on click of a leaflet marker. 
using histroy.pushState results in url change, but i don't get the `route params` in my `react` components.

so to bypass this i global `this.props.history` as History and then use its `push` method to change the state.

is there a better way to do this... using this feels wrong... like a monkey patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux), there are some [useful actions](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#pushlocation-replacelocation-gonumber-goback-goforward) that you can use to change location as long as you have access to the store.

Comment: i dont know about  `react-router-redux` it is in `alpha` is it stable ?

Comment: version 5 is in alpha, [version 4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-redux) is definitely stable and very widely used.

Comment: Cool, will check it out.

Comment: checked it out, it won't work with react-router-v4 as version 4 of RRR uses functions of React Router V3

Comment: oh, sorry about that.

Comment: @MujtabaKably There is actually a [version of react-router-redux](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux) which works with RR 4.